# When does a 'symbol' / 'variable name' get created in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, php-internals

This is my setting: 
display_startup_errors = on 
display_errors = On 
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT

```
//code1:
$a = "abcd";
xdebug_debug_zval('a');
```

The above line of code would create a zval container and associate it with the symbol a'. And would give the following o/p.

```
a: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)='abcd'
```

consider the folowing code now:

```
//code2:
$a;
echo":";xdebug_debug_zval('a'); echo "<br/>";
$a = "abcd";
xdebug_debug_zval('a'); echo "<br/>";
```

would generate the o/p;

```
:
a: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)='abcd'
```

from PHP manual's [Reference Counting Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php) : A zval container is created when a **new variable is created** with a constant value

Does this mean that,

> 1] No symbol is created when code similar to *line 1 of code2* i.e. `$a;` is encountered. Since     xdebug_debug_zval does not find the symbol / variable name 'a'. As per the statement from     [Reference Counting Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php) no zval container is created.
>   2] A symbol is created only when code similar to *line 3 of code2* i.e. `$a = "abcd";` is encountered.     i.e. a symbol gets created only when the variable is associated with a constant value & as per the     statement from [Reference Counting Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php) a zval container is created and is associated with the     symbol 'a'. And that *line 1 of code2 i.e. `$a;` is a useless piece of code*.

For info on xdebug_debug_zval visit [here](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions).

Comment: Did you notice the, uh, notice?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams pardon me. What are you intending to tell?

Comment: The notice that shows up when you try to read from a variable that doesn't exist. Of course, you can only see it if you have showing of notices enabled...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams
yes I can see the errors if there are any: this is my setting:
display_startup_errors = on
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Have added an answer on my inference.

Comment: The *Question* has the *Answer*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$b;
xdebug_debug_zval('b'); echo "<br/> ";
echo $b;
```

The above code would output:

> Notice: Undefined variable: b in /path/to/file/file.php on line 'some line number'

The xdebug_debug_zval is not throwing any error in the above code though!!

Assigining $b a constant value,

```
$b = "hello";
xdebug_debug_zval('b'); echo "<br/> ";
echo $b;
```

> b: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)='hello'
>   hello

The above code proves that a 'symbol'/'variable name' gets created only when a constant is associated with it
i.e.
 A 'symbol'/'variable name' gets created only when there is a possibility of a zval getting created.

A symbol can be created if a variable is assigned *NULL*.

```
$b = null;
xdebug_debug_zval('b'); echo "<br/> ";
echo $b;
```

The above code will output:

> b: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)=NULL